# Creating Entity Framework "code-first from database" classes/model at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Suppose at runtime I have sufficient information to access a database and retrieve a schema description of the view/table that defines all the fields, types, etc., e.g. a connection string, a password and a view/table name.

If I do design time "code-first from database" in Visual Studio with the above information, a class is created that that can be used to create a C# object corresponding to a row in the view/table and there is a class created that is derived from `DbContext` that initializes the `DbConext` with the connection string and also defines `OnModelCreating()`.

Could someone point me to example of how the how I can use the retrieved schema description at runtime to generate the two classes needed by EF?

This is my first time using this forum. What is a good set of terms to use to refine my search? I tried "creating Entity Framework model at runtime".

I will be using EF 6+

Comment: Sounds quite tricky. Why do you need this and how are you going to use these runtime generated classes?

Comment: This"feature" will be part of a larger application that is basically a database viewer where at runtime the user selects a database and a view/table. Basically I am trying to do the same thing the Entity Framework wizard does in Visual Studio: open db and table, read table structure information and build runtime access to the data in the table.

Comment: But when you have the classes done, how would you actually use them? I would say it's probably a lot easier to just build a system that retrieves the metadata and handles it in code than create classes at runtime and try to use them for something